# connect to openvpn 2.3.10 with AES-128-CBC

Tags: openvpn

I have ubuntu 20.04 with openvpn 2.4.7 client and want to connect to a openvpn 2.3.10 server with AES-128-CBC

This is my client.conf

```
port 443
client
dev tun
proto tcp4-client
remote [the.vpnserver.ip]
remote-cert-tls server

ca   /etc/openvpn/server-ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/fb3.sbs.crt
key  /etc/openvpn/fb3.sbs.key

cipher AES-128-CBC
data-ciphers AES-128-CBC
data-ciphers-fallback AES-128-CBC

nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
log-append /var/log/openvpn.log
script-security 2
tls-cipher "DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=0"
```

When I start openvpn client I get this error.

```
ovpn-client[7357]: Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in /etc/openvpn/client.conf:13: data-ciphers (2.4.7)
ovpn-client[7357]: Use --help for more information.
systemd[1]: openvpn@client.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: openvpn@client.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```